# StoreFile for Telerik (FileBrowser Content Provider) override it

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, telerik, object-storage, file-browser

I am overriding below method of Telerik (FileBrowser Content Provider) to deal with Saving File on disk and Object Storage AWS

```
public override string StoreFile(UploadedFile file, string path, string name, params string[] arguments)
{
    return base.StoreFile(file, path, name, arguments);
}
```

The path paramater of StoreFile works fine in case of file saving to disk but in case of Object Storage AWS it does not.
Scenario - if path is like '/Object/Stack OverFlow'/ it works fine for disk but for object storage it gives same path as '/Object' , it ignores folder with (Space, Special characters etc.)

How to get this complete path in case of Object Storage AWS ?

Answer (score 0):

For the path use the Path class instead of string
and then you can use Path.Combine
and if it's still not working then you need to use verbatim strings.
just add @ in front of the string and then it ignores the special characters.